# Jupyter notebook : how to convert to PDF?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I am running Python programs on `jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3` and I would like to convert a notebook into a PDF format. So:
Inside my notebook, I click on `"File"` then `"Download as"`, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

If I take `"PDF via Latex"` I get an error, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

If I take `"PDF via HTML"`, I get a not so bad PDF on the screen, but **on 1 page only**, and not printable...

Could you help me and tell me how do you proceed to convert a notebook to a PDF?

I specify:

- that the `"PDF via Latex"` method worked a few months ago; but I don't use it often and today it doesn't work anymore.
- that in order to use the `"PDF via HTML"` method, I ran the commands `python -m pip install -U notebook-as-pdf` and `pyppeteer-install`, as indicated in [this page](https://pypi.org/project/notebook-as-pdf/)

Comment: I had the same problem but couldn't fix it. I tried some suggestions that didn't work then switched to open a jupyter notebook with jupyter lab.   This worked.

Comment: @Sonji, I did open my jupyter notebook with jupyter lab, as you recommended; but I am stuck with the next step: how do you convert to PDF? Don't find the way...

Comment: Check this link out. It illustrates it well. https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/export.html

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately, the issue came from the fact that I introduced a `Markdown` cell in my Notebook ! Keeping this cell, neither from jupyter notebook, nor from jupyter lab, I was able to download to PDF. Removing this cell, I now can use the `"PDF via Latex"` method from inside my jupyter notebook, and it works ! The problem seems to come from mixing `Python` and `Markdown` cells in the same notebook. Surprising...